# jQuery UI Autocomplete JSON gives error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '62' in

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am having a great deal of trouble getting autocomplete to work on my page. When I enter 2 characters ("OW") into my search input, I get the preloader image (see below), but it never goes away and I never get the autocomplete popup. Looking at the console in Chrome shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '62' in [{"value":103,"label":"FLOWER"},{"value":105,"label":"YELLOW"}]
```

Here is the actual string that is being returned (confirmed by adding an alert(data) in the success block):

```
[{"kwrdID":103,"kwrdKeyWord":"FLOWER"},{"kwrdID":105,"kwrdKeyWord":"YELLOW"}]
```

Here is the main code for the autocomplete

```
$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetKeywords", "Home")',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            SearchTerm: request.term
        },
        success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data.keywords, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.kwrdKeyWord,
                    value: item.kwrdID
                }
            }));
        }
    });
},
    minLength: 2
});
```

And finally, here is the preloader (just in case it's related).

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    var position = $('#divParent').position();
    position.left += (($('#divParent').width() / 2) - ($('#preloader').width() / 2));
    position.top += (($('#divParent').height() / 2) - ($('#preloader').height() / 2));
    $('#preloader').css(position).show();
    $('#preloader').show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#preloader').hide();
});
```

Can anyone help to explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was a long road, but after many hours of experimenting I came up with this code:

```
$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetKeywords", "Home")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                SearchTerm: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
                var newArray = new Array(parsed.length);
                var i = 0;

                parsed.forEach(function (entry) {
                    var newObject = {
                        label: entry.kwrdKeyWord
                    };
                    newArray[i] = newObject;
                    i++;
                });

                response(newArray);
            },
            error: function (message) {
                response([]);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

This appears to work fine. The truth is my keywords are unique, so I can live without the ID anyway.

Comment: I think what fixed it is the `JSON.parse` call.

Answer (score 9):

a little help that can be useful:

if you're using json, it might be that the "json object" isn't parsed, or you've overwritten the variable with others tings (like what I did stupidly recently).

for the first problem, be sure that your server know "application/json" MIME type, else use header (for PHP)

I mean, in PHP, use this before all:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks @NereoCostacurta. Struggled with the same error for quite a while; my server-side code is in ColdFusion. Therefore, using `<cfcontent type="text/json">` at the top of my script resolved the issue instantly.

Comment: Woah there nelly, who said anything about PHP

Comment: @AdamF problems can come from any place. if you just echo the json in php, but you don't set the right header, jquery can fail to parse the object retrieved by ajax, even if you specified datatype as JSON. by the way, this is an old answer from january 2014, don't know if current jquery handles better the parsing now.

Answer (score 0):

here how you use the function for the source property

```
source:function(request,response) {
    var url = "your url";
    var postdata = "your data"; // normally you might use request.term to get the current user input
    $.ajax({url:url,data:postdata,success:function(responsedata){
        response($.parseJSON(responsedata))
    }});
}
```

The response function accepts array of JSON objects

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing replace `data.keywords` with `JSON.parse(data)` at this line : `response($.map(data.keywords, function (item) {`.

BR,
Hazem

Comment: This needs some tidying up, for example include the full code example; use correct indenting and explain your answer full. Also as a sign note do not sign off your answers.