# jQueryUI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to make an autocomplete with remote source (json) but I can't figure out what should i do to make it work.

I get responses like:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 4,
  "data": [
    {
      "nickname": "Deadly",
      "id": 501689800
    },
    {
      "nickname": "Deadly00",
      "id": 517095041
    },
    {
      "nickname": "Deadly001",
      "id": 504471830
    },
    {
      "nickname": "DeadLy01",
      "id": 500877077
    }
  ]
}
```

Script I'm using:

```
$(function() {
    var cache = {};
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function(request, response) {
                    var term = request.term;
                    if (term in cache) {
                        response(cache[term]);
                        return;
                    }
            $.getJSON("path/to/heaven/" + term, function(data) {
                cache[term] = data;
                response(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Autocomplete shows proper amount of "suggestion fields" but the only content there is "ok".
Ho do I change it so it would show nicknames?

Comment: `response(data)` should be `response($.map(data.data, function(e){return e.nickname}))`. Note about the `data.data`, the `data` passed in is the whole object (as described in the response in your question), this object has a `data` property.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of response(data), try the below.

```
response($.map(data, function(item) {
    return {
        value: item.nickname
    }
}))
```

In case if you are getting any error, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966487/jquery-ui-autocomplete-json-gives-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-ope)

Comment: This causes suggestion list to generate proper amount of results but they're all empty.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/C5xvH/)**

You should use like

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
//source: availableTags
    source: function(request, response) {
            var term = request.term;
            $.getJSON("path/to/heaven/" + term, function(data) {
                cache[term] = data;
                //response(data);
                response($.map(data.data, function(item) {
                return {
                    value: item.nickname
                }
                }));
            });        

        }
});
```