# How to parse returned JSON array to populate JQueryUI Automcomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

This is success part of my jquery ajax call:

```
dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {                            
                            return {                                
                                label: item.ItemName,
                                val: item.ItemId
                            }
                        }))
                    },
```

And this is `data` that I get in this success block from server:

```
[{"ItemId":1095,"ItemName":"Double Axe"},{"ItemId":1096,"ItemName":"Helm"},{"ItemId":1097,"ItemName":"Armor"},{"ItemId":1098,"ItemName":"Gloves"},{"ItemId":1099,"ItemName":"Boots"}]
```

Error that I am getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Problem is that `response($.map(data.d, function (item) {` is never executed.
What should I do to make this work?

Comment: If `data` is the JSON that you gave above, then there is no `data.d`, right?

Comment: Yes. Data.d is nothing

Comment: Well that's your problem, no? Shouldn't it just be `$.map(data, function...`

Comment: @1110 Then why are you iterating over *nothing* and expecting something to happen..?

Comment: @PatrickQ but if I pass `data` inside I get error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '180' in [{"ItemId":1095,"ItemName":"Double Axe"},{"ItemId":1095,"ItemName":"Helm"},{"ItemId":1095,"ItemName":"Armor"},{"ItemId":1095,"ItemName":"Gloves"},{"ItemId":1095,"ItemName":"Boots"}] `

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your `response()` function.

Comment: I have tried to replace `val` with `value` but still doesn't work.

Comment: Without seeing the code for the `response()` function, we can't say what the problem is.  If you pass `data` instead of `data.d` the map function itself works just fine.

Comment: This question appears related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966487/jquery-ui-autocomplete-json-gives-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-ope

Comment: Yes. Solution is `var parsed = JSON.parse(data);` now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently passing a json *string* to the `$.map()` method which expects an array or object. parsing the response you're getting using `JSON.parse()`.

Following seems to be working fine:

```js
var data = [{
  "ItemId": 1095,
  "ItemName": "Double Axe"
}, {
  "ItemId": 1096,
  "ItemName": "Helm"
}, {
  "ItemId": 1097,
  "ItemName": "Armor"
}, {
  "ItemId": 1098,
  "ItemName": "Gloves"
}, {
  "ItemId": 1099,
  "ItemName": "Boots"
}];
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  "source": function(request, response) {
    response($.map(data, function(item) {
      return {
        label: item.ItemName,
        val: item.ItemId
      }
    }));
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>
```